# How can I override a function with various inherited arguments (Swift)

Tags: swift, inheritance, overriding, abstract-class, extends

How to override a function with an inherited argument in Swift?

I have classes:

```
class ItemA {
    var valueA: String?
    func setValueA(_ value: String?) {
        valueA = value
    }
}

class ItemB: ItemA {
    var valueB: String?
    func setValueB(_ value: String?) {
        valueB = value
    }
}

// Analog of the abstract class
class ClassA {
    func setValues(_ item: ItemA) {
        item.setValueA("valueA")
        getValues(item) // call getValues from ClassB
    }
    func getValues(_ item: ItemA) {
        abort()
    }
}

class ClassB: ClassA {
    override func setValues(_ item: ItemB) { // item have type itemB, but extends ItemA
        item.setValueB("valueB")
        super.setValues(item)
    }
    override func getValues(_ item: ItemA) {
        let item = item as! ItemB
        let array = [item.valueA, item.valueB]
        print(array)
    }
}
```

My goal is to get the following results:

```
let itemB = ItemB()
ClassB().setValues(itemB)
// print ["valueA", "valueB"]
```

I can't override the function in the class because the types are different and there is no type inheritance in Swift. I get this error in `setValues(_ item: ItemB)` method from `ClassB`:

> Method does not override any method from its superclass

In Java, this can be implemented using an abstract class and an extensible type:

```
abstract class ClassA {
    <T extends ItemA> void setValues(T item) {
    item.setValueA("valueA");
        getValues(item);
    }
    abstract void getValues(MainItem item);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct answer depends on generics:

```
class ItemA {
    var valueA: String?
    func setValueA(_ value: String?) {
        valueA = value
    }
}

class ItemB: ItemA {
    var valueB: String?
    func setValueB(_ value: String?) {
        valueB = value
    }
}

// Analog of the abstract class
class ClassA {
    func setValues<T : ItemA>(_ item: T) {
        item.setValueA("valueA")
        getValues(item) // call getValues from ClassB
    }
    func getValues(_ item: ItemA) {
        abort()
    }
}

class ClassB: ClassA {
    override func setValues<T : ItemB>(_ item: T) {
        // item have type itemB, but extends ItemA
        item.setValueB("valueB")
        super.setValues(item)
    }
    override func getValues(_ item: ItemA) {
        let item = item as! ItemB
        let array = [item.valueA, item.valueB]
        print(array)
    }
}
```

Check it! If you want to print non-optional values, unwrap them.

```
    let itemB = ItemB()
    ClassB().setValues(itemB)
    // print ["valueA", "valueB"]
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you very much!

Comment: This answer doesn't solve the problem that the other answer highlights (that casting your `ClassB` to `ClassA` allows you to pass an `ItemA` to it).

Comment: It is another task with another functions `setValues` and `getValues`. Just write another methods to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

`ClassB.setValues` can't accept an argument of type `ItemB` (even though it's a subclass of `ItemA`), because doing so would violate the Liskov substitution principle.

`ClassB` instances need to be able to do anything that `ClassA` instances can. One such requirement is to accept `ItemA` arguments to its `setValues` method. Otherwise, what would happen in this code?

```
let classAInst: ClassA = ClassB()
classAInstance.setValues(ItemA())
```

Comment: This does not solve my problem. In this case, I’ll get `["valueA"]` instead of `["valueA", "valueB"]`, since it will only work `ClassA` with `ItemA`.

Comment: You can solve the problem with generics as well as in java. I have providied correct answer above.